# Electromagnetic "floating" noise in circuit have a frequency component that affects impedance of input pin?

Tags: impedance

> *"The effects of capacitance and inductance vary with frequency, so if these are present the input impedance will vary with frequency. The
> effects of capacitance and inductance are generally most significant
> at high frequencies. "* - https://electronicsclub.info/impedance.htm

Does the "noise" that causes floating logic in disconnected input pins tend to have a frequency component (the "antenna" metaphor is often used, and "antennas" definately pick up different frequencies) that affects the impedance of the input it affects?

Comment: Digital folks might think "CMOS input" or old farts might think "TTL input". Or analog folks might think of an oscilloscope input (1 Megohm, or perhaps 10 Megohm). Or audio folks might consider an input around 10k ohm. All are affected more at higher frequencies, but each has a different frequency where it *begins* to be sensitive. So you might add more context to your question - input to *what*?

Comment: White noise contains all frequencies. Different-coloured noise has different mixtures of frequencies.

Comment: The main (dominant) source of noise will be the AC mains voltage 50Hz/100Hz or 60Hz/120Hz. And the switchmode power supplies from 20kHz to 1MHz.

Comment: (And then all of the odd harmonics thereof...)  And if traces and/or wires are long enough and unshielded, octaves of induced RF... literal antennae.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. If I ask like this, given what @G36 said, that most noise is AC mains voltage. And, the logic device is getting DC input usually, if I understand right. Is there an effect in the impedance of the input pin where the DC has an easier time passing through than the AC noise?

Answer (score 1):

Every frequency component in the noise will see a different impedance if we assume that the input is mainly capacitive. That's just the definition of impedance for a capacitor.

Your statement "the noise that causes floating logic" doesn't make sense. Logic signals are floating if they are not actively driven. Noise can induce a **voltage** on such a signal, as can the leakage currents of the various diodes and transistors that are intentionally connected to that signal.

The spectrum of any radiated or conducted noise will depend very heavily on exactly how the circuit is constructed and the environment in which it operates, from dc to light.

Comment: "the noise that causes floating logic" makes perfect sense. The question, if frequency affects impedance of input pin, might not make sense on the other hand. But have zero interest in arguing, was trying to understand something. Peace.

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, every single person emphasizes the "noise" from outside machine over leakage current, like here, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/247645. I can't say for sure myself, maybe leakage currents are a bigger issue, but what I wrote definitely makes sense. There are probably things to pick on in the question but not that.. Peace.

Comment: Note that both of the answers to your duplicate question talk about the importance of leakage current. And I think you are confusing cause and effect...a signal is floating because it is not driven, full stop. What **happens** to that floating input depends on its environment. It will not necessarily increase in voltage.

Comment: They're not duplicate. And leakage current is probably important, like you said. But what people usually emphasize is not it, so, that's why I phrased myself like I did. In the case of AC noise, leakage current probably does not apply that much since it would be DC, if logical circuits tend to run on DC? (read that somewhere).

Comment: re: "a signal is floating because it is not driven, full stop", seems a bit exaggerated to say that I mix up cause and effect. If what happens to the floating input depends on the environment. More that you define "floating" as the ability to change state, and I used as when it actually changes state. But, not sure if arguing about that relates to the question or adds anything.

Comment: "Floating" is a condition, not an event. Sorry if you have misunderstood that, but that's the way it is. It is important to clarify this so the next reader does not become confused.

Comment: I haven't misunderstood it. Writing "floating logic" instead of "logic input switching during condition floating, which is not an event", is understandable. People understood it. If there is a much better terminology, you may point it out, or I might notice it eventually, but in this context it is no issue.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the "noise" that causes floating logic in disconnected input pins tend to have a frequency component (the "antenna" metaphor is often used, and "antennas" definately pick up different frequencies) that affects the impedance of the input it affects?

Yes, the noise will have a mixture of frequency components.  What those are depends on what is nearby causing the noise.  Frequencies of 50 or 60Hz (depending on where you live) are likely, and possibly 100Hz or 120Hz too.
If there are other signals nearby on the circuit board, these could also induce voltages into the floating input whether by inductance, capacitive coupling, or leakage resistance (especially in humid conditions).

Logic inputs on integrated circuits tend to have a small capacitance, often listed in the data sheet.  This is just in the nature of the IC, and is not a deliberate feature.  The impedance of a capacitor is given by

```
X = 1/(2πfC)
```

where f is the frequency and C is the capacitance.  So it's pretty much a given that the impedance of an IC with a specified capacitance in its input pin will vary with frequency.

*But having said that, I'm not sure if it's any real use to know what the impedance would be at any frequency of stray noise picked up.  Even if you calculate it, what are you going to do with that information?  The sensible thing would be to ensure that the input wasn't left floating in the first place.*

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat of an academic exercise as no one nowadays leaves an input to a CMOS or any other device, deliberately floating.

This is one of those places where you can spend lots of time and money with an E&M modeling tool, simulating your input structure, the ESD protection network, and the trace/wire going to the outside world to figure how how vulnerable you are to coupled noise, assuming, of course, that you have a good model of your environment - that is, that you know what your potential coupling sources are.

Or, you can be proactive and just not leave any input floating.